# Hadoop CLI command to get Total Memory Used, etc like shown in Hadoop Web UI on 8088

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is there a CLI command I can use to get the Metrics show in this picture as they appear in the Hadoop Web UI on 8088?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK no. Why do want them in command line ?

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram because I want to log and track total cluster memory usage across a job.

Answer (score 0):

`yarn top` would show this.  It works similar to the UNIX/Linux command `top`.

Source code at https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/cli/TopCLI.java: